# BJT mosfet fan driver circuit

Tags: bjt, mosfet-driver, fan

I am working on trying to understand more about a fan control circuit I came across and tested.
J1 will be connected to a 3.3V fan. My goal is to slowly turn the fan on depending on the temperature of some other chip, by using the PWM signal. I need the fan (J1 pin 2) to receive 2.2V at 50% duty cycle and 3.3V at 100% duty cycle.

Here is my understanding:

- The user chooses what power source to power the fan with (3.3 or 5)
- The PMOS is pulled high and is thus off initially (with no PWM signal)
- The BJT base is pulled high so when there is no PWM it is not floating
- R5 limits the current to the base
- When the PWM signal starts, at let's say 50% duty cycle, the BJT should pull the PMOS gate down to turn the PMOS on and let the fan receive current.
- As the PWM signal keeps going higher, lets say to 75%, the BJT should pull the gate even lower to turn the PMOS on more and let the fan receive even more current. And this continues to 100%.

My question is, without simulation, how can I calculate or get a rough estimate of what resistor values to choose? I want to avoid guess and check.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According your description you dont want feed fan with pulsed voltage but continous DC, right? Than you need an amplifier, or even better controlled current source. How do you generate the PWM, because for both solution is better a voltage signal (not PWM). If you want PWM to controll DC you must use a RC filter after PWM to obtain DC controll signal.